# Assigning global/reactive variables

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am pretty new to Shiny and have perhaps therefore difficulties wrapping my head around how to convert ordinary R-code into usable Shiny-code.

I wish to use code I have already written in R, which transorms a CSV file and creates several different data frames and writes them to an output. The reason I use Shiny is to make it easier for a user to use and change input variables.

I have for example the following code:

```r
X <- Y %>% filter(grepl("FALSE", ignore.case=T, ZZ)==F | is.na(ZY), KKL!="PLO")
X.Y <- X %>% filter(grepl("ZZZ", ignore.case = T, PLOP==T)
X.YY <- X%>% filter(grepl("ZIZ", ignore.case = T, PLK)==T)
```

I tried creating those variables by applying `observeEvent` triggered by the user uploading the relevant CSV-file, however, I figured out that the `observeEvent` creates and stores local values, which won't do when I wish to write the data frames to outputs. Does this mean that I have to, for each of the the above commands, create a separate reactive function reactive functions? Or is there a way to globally assign these variables as in standard R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you expect to "deploy" this shiny app? If it's always going to be run locally only, then you can have a trigger (`actionButton`) that stops the app and returns a value with `stopApp(list(dat1, dat2, dat3))`. You would likely call this with `list_of_frames <- my_shiny_app(something, goes, here)`, which would take your inputs, start the shiny app, then return your newly created frames into the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a reactive function for each of these assignments :

```
X <- reactive( Y() %>% filter(grepl("FALSE", ignore.case=T, ZZ)==F | is.na(ZY), KKL!="PLO") )
X.Y <- reactive( X() %>% filter(grepl("ZZZ", ignore.case = T, PLOP==T) )
X.YY <- reactive( X() %>% filter(grepl("ZIZ", ignore.case = T, PLK)==T) )
```

`X.Y` and `X.YY`depend on `X` and will update automatically after changes on `X`.
`Y`should also be reactive, for example :

```
  Y <- eventReactive(input$loadCSVbutton, {
    readCSV("mydata.csv")
  })
```

Note that as `X`and `Y`are now reactive functions, their value is `X()`and `Y()`

Comment: Thank you!  Would it be possible to put all the dataframes i an eventReactive function?

Comment: It depends on the variables you need to render your UI : they all have to be reactive. If X is only an intermediate calculation you don't use for UI rendering, you can put it after readCSV in eventReactive and output directly X instead of Y

Comment: That is right, many of data frames are used to store intermediate calculations. So I could do something like:  eventReactive(input$loadCSVbutton, {
    Y <- readCSV("mydata.csv") X <-  Y %>% filter(grepl("FALSE", ignore.case=T, ZZ)==F | is.na(ZY), KKL!="PLO") )
   })

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but does the code become more inefficient with storing every variable as a reactive function?

Comment: In my experience, the code can manage tens of reactives. Try it as you proposed in your previous comment.